# Считать из файла и суммировать

Tags: c#, файлы, суммирование

В файл ранее были записаны числа с плавающей точкой, новое число в новой строке. Необходимо считать их из файла и суммировать. Код для считывания работает, а сумму выдает, но, для определенного тестового варианта 124 + 128, выдает 256, вместо 252. В чем может быть проблема и как это можно исправить?
код:

```
         string line = null;
         int t=0;

          while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(line);
              t = int.Parse(line);

             Console.WriteLine("TUT" + t);

         }
         t += t;
         Console.WriteLine( "TUT" + t);
```

Comment: где тут сложение 124 + 128???  t += t; это значит  128 += 128 и 256 правильный ответ

Comment: а еще "числа с плавающей точкой" и int.Parse - в int точки не плавают

Comment: а ещё сложение надо делать в цикле, а не за ним

Comment: Зачем так много кода? `File.ReadLines(path).Select(double.Parse).Sum()`.

Comment: @ValeraKvip поняла ситуацию. а как можно сделать так, чтобы суммировало именно необходимые элементы?

Comment: @VladD числа за точкой-нули. их присутствие не важно. поэтому в int. Пробовала и в цикле. Был такой же результат

Comment: @ Rrttr найти их и просуммировать.  " Пробовала и в цикле. Был такой же результат" такой же быть не мог, если там не одно число

Answer (score 1):

Приведенный вами пример кода не вполне достаточен. По нему сложно воспроизвести проблему. Но я попробую угадать.

На каждом шаге цикла вы заново читаете переменную `t`, никуда не сохранив её предыдущее значение. После выхода из цикла вы суммируете `t` с самой собой. Ставлю на то, что последнее число в вашем файле - это 128. Тогда на выходе из цикла у вас получается 128 + 128 = 256 (`t += t`).

Итого:

- Производите суммирование внутри цикла, а не после выхода из него.
- Читая данные из файла, не затирайте ими сумму.